# When is it written with and without accent: porqué/porque/por qué? / ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "porque", "porqué", "por que" y "por qué"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, ortografía, acentuación, preguntas-canónicas

> This is a [canonical question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674) / Esta es una [pregunta canónica](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674)

Can anybody explain to me when each of this variations of "porque" should be used?

---

¿Puede alguien explicar cuáles son las diferencias entre "porque", "porqué", "por que" y "por qué"?

Comment: I would like to point out that these words are pronounced differently. The stress falls on the second syllable in "por qué" and "porqué," while it falls on the first syllable in "porque."

Comment: Related: [Ortografía: por qué, porque, por que, porqué](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/286/22)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Por qué** asks the question *why*.

> ¿Por qué hiciste eso?

**Porque** means *because*.

> Porque puedo.

**Porqué** translates roughly to *reason*.

> Quiero saber el porqué de esta decisión.

Comment: I should add that there's a fourth alternative: "por que", which means "por el/la cual" or "por los/las cuales" (Esa fue la razón *por que* lo echaron a la calle). It can also be *por + que as "conjunción subordinante"* (El éxito en una carrera pasa *por que* estudies cada día = [...] pasa por estudiar [...]). In [this link](http://cvc.cervantes.es/alhabla/museo_horrores/museo_009.htm) you can find an explanation of the four cases, with all the proper gramatical names, which I have long forgotten.

Answer (score 12):

**ENGLISH -Spanish follows**

Check the RAE on [Porqué / porque / por qué / por que](http://www.rae.es/consultas/porque-porque-por-que-por-que) for a deep explanation of this. There are several combinations (*porque* vs. *por que* as one or two words and then *que/qué* with or without the accent)

1- You use *por qué* as two words and with the accents for **questions**:

> ¿Por qué es eso así?
>
> Me pregunto por qué Jorge está tan enfadado<sub>(talking to oneself)</sub>.

Or in exclamation:

> ¡Por qué sitios más bonitos hemos pasado de camino aquí!

Using *por que* in a question is a misspelling. You need the accent.

2- You use *porque*, as a single word and without the accent **to explain something**.

> ¿Por qué llora el bebé?
> Llora **porque** tiene tiene hambre.

3- *Porqué*, is a noun. We could actually understand is as a *pronoun* which stands for "the reason or the rationale behind this or that"

> No comprendo el porqué de ese razonamiento. No comprendo el porqué (la razón) de eso.

4- *Por que* (two words, no accent) is the use of the preposition *por* and the relative pronoun *que*, which is quite complex (not only for this specific use, but for many others). Basically that *que* is introducing a second sentence, subordinate to the firs one. Along with the use of the preposition *por* the second sentence is explaining the *why* or the first sentence.

> Esa es la razón por que llora el bebé = Esa es la razón por **la** que llora el bebé.

As a note apart, see that you could use this construction with other prepositions, like *para*:

> Le he dado un biberón al bebé **para que** coma

The use of *para* here also helps introducing the subordinate sentence that explains the first sentence.

But, please, check the link I gave you. It is really good. If you have problems understating that in Spanish tell us and we can help with some translations of those rules.

---

**ESPAÑOL**

Comprueba en la RAE [Porqué / porque / por qué / por que](http://www.rae.es/consultas/porque-porque-por-que-por-que) para una explicación más extensa. Hay varias combinaciones (*porque* vs. *por que* una o dos palabras y también *que/qué* con o sin acento)

1- Se utiliza *por qué* formado por dos palabras y tilde para **preguntas**:

> ¿Por qué es eso así?
>
> Me pregunto por qué Jorge está tan enfadado<sub>(hablando hacia uno mismo)</sub>.

O en exclamaciones:

> ¡Por qué sitios más bonitos hemos pasado de camino aquí!

Utilizar *por que* en una pregunta es un error ortográfico. Es necesario poner la tilde.

2- Se utiliza *porque* con una única palabra y sin tilde **para explicar algo**.

> ¿Por qué llora el bebé?
> Llora **porque** tiene tiene hambre.

3- *Porqué* es un sustantivo. Podríamos entenderlo como un *pronombre* que significa "la razón o la razón que hay detrás de esto o aquello"

> No comprendo el porqué de ese razonamiento. No comprendo el porqué (la razón) de eso.

4- *Por que* (dos palabras, sin acento) es el uso de la preposición *por* y el pronombre relativo *que*, que es bastante complejo (no solo para este uso específico, tiene muchos otros). Básicamente *que* introduce una segunda frase subordinada de la primera.  A través del uso de la preposición *por* la segunda frase explica el porqué de la primera frase.

> Esa es la razón por que llora el bebé = Esa es la razón por **la** que llora el bebé.

Como nota aparte, también podemos utilizar esta construcción con otras preposiciones como *para*:

> Le he dado un biberón al bebé **para que** coma

El uso de *para* aquí también ayuda a introducir una subordinada que explica la primera frase.

Pero, por favor, comprueba el enlace que te he dejado. Es realmente bueno.

Comment: ¡Gran respuesta! Siempre das explicaciones buenas y útiles, que van incluso más allá de la pregunta concreta. Precisamente esto buscaba con el "bounty", que espero sirva para seguir dando información "canónica" a la página. Gracias

Answer (score 6):

- *¿Por qué?* is used in questions, and it means literally **why?**
- *Porque* is the answer to a question asked with *¿Por qué?* and it means **because**
- *Porqué* is a sustantive, it'd mean **the reason for**