# "No tiene por qué pagar" vs "No tiene que pagar"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, conjunciones, diferencias-entre-palabras

Por favor, vea el vinculo siguiente:https://elpais.com/elpais/2020/02/07/eps/1581073136_206237.html

Tengo un problema con la frase

> Un ciudadano de a pie **no tiene por qué pagar** la propaganda de ningún partido.

¿Por qué se utiliza  "no tiene **por qué** pagar.." y no "no tiene **que** pagar"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La diferencia es sutil pero

> "no tiene que pagar"

significa, "está libre de la responsabilidad (de pagar)".

Por ejemplo:

> Si usted es menor de 12 años o mayor de 65 **no tiene que pagar** esta entrada. Para estos grupos la entrada es gratis.

Por otro lado

> "no tiene por qué pagar"

significa que el individuo ya está pagando por algo, pero no necesita (o no debería necesitar o tener obligación de) hacerlo. (They don't need to do it/ they don't have to do it)

Decir

> Un ciudadano de a pie **no tiene por qué pagar** la propaganda de ningún partido.

Cuestiona que el ciudadano debe hacer frente a dicha carga: "no hay razón para que ese el ciudadanos deba pagar la propaganda de ningún partido político". (They **should not** have to do it/ they **should not** need to do it)

---

It could be useful to check this pre-existing question: [When is it written with and without accent: porqué/porque/por qué? / ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre “porque”, “porqué”, “por que” y “por qué”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/14/5481), since it clarifies not only accentuation but usage of some of these words.

Comment: Gracias.¡ Una respuesta dabuti !