# Por qué o porqué o porque

Tags: selección-de-palabras

¿En la siguiente frase, qué opción es la más correcta? Se refiere a "ya no hay motivo para" jugar a esos juegos.

*No hay juegos que jugar ni **por que** jugarlos.*

He mirado la [RAE](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/porque-porque-por-que-por-que-0) pero no me aclaro.

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta preexitente responderá a todas tus dudas: [When is it written with and without accent: porqué/porque/por qué? / ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre “porque”, “porqué”, “por que” y “por qué”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/14/5481). Tanto es así que la hemos marcado como **canónica**. Mira el cuarto punto de [mi respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/13503/5481) a esa pregunta:

Comment: Gracias por el link Diego, había visto la explicación de la RAE pero seguía sin tenerlo claro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Por qué**.

Como se puede ver en la [explicación](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/porque-porque-por-que-y-por-que-935/):

> Por qué es la combinación de la preposición por y el
> interrogativo qué: «¿Por qué no aumenta el número de vivienda
> protegida?»; se reconoce si se le agrega la palabra razón: «Le
> preguntaron por qué (razón) ingresó al club».

En la frase de tu ejemplo, podrías perfectamente decir "ni por qué razón jugarlos" y el significado sigue igual.

Comment: Muy bueno el truco de meterle "razón" en medio. Muy buena respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Por qué significa por qué razón y se usa para hacer una pregunta pidiendo la razón de algo. Por ejemplo, "¿ Por qué debo comer la sopa ?" Y el papá dice algo como,
" Porque si la comes gozarás de buena salud. " Cuando las dos palabras por y que forman una sola palabra es para responder a una pregunta.

La pregunta y la respuesta de arriba es un resumen de una conversación entre Malfalda (tira cómica famosa de Quinto) y sus padres.